# Picking a team using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to write a program that shows all possible combinations of teams with characters A,B,C... and so on.

**Input : (5,3)**

**5 is the group size and 3 is the team size.**

**choosing 3 out of {A,B,C,D,E}**

*Expected output : ABC,ABD,ABE,ACD,ACE,ADE,BCD,BCE,BDE,CDE*

Below is the code I've written so far.

```
public class teamApp 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int groupSize =5;
        int teamSize = 3;
        char start = 'A';
        String sequence = "";
        showTeam(sequence,start,groupSize,teamSize);
    }

    public static void showTeam(String sequence,char start, int n, int k)
    {
        if(n==0||k==0||k>n) {
            System.out.println(sequence);
            return;
        } else {
            showTeam(sequence+start,start++,n-1,k-1);       
            showTeam(sequence,start++,n-1,k);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use the `(n,k) = (n-1,k-1)+(n-1,k)` theorem. (where **n=groupSize k=teamSize**). My current output is

```
AAA
AAB
AAC
AA
ABB
ABC
AB
ACC
AC
A
BBB
BBC
BB
BCC
BC
B
CCC
CC
C
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: as a sidenode to this, the `return` is unnecessary

Comment: Just a side note: don't use static main to test your code. Write unit tests instead. Using unit tests, you can start with small examples; and you have implicit checking. That is **much** better than just print stuff to the console. As it is way too easy to overlook when your algorithm is just "slightly" incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should change

```
showTeam(sequence+start,start++,n-1,k-1);
showTeam(sequence,start++,n-1,k);
```

to

```
showTeam(sequence+start,(char)(start+1),n-1,k-1);
showTeam(sequence,(char)(start+1),n-1,k);
```

otherwise, only the second recursive call would get the incremented value of `start` (since `start++` returns the original value of `start`).

Second of all, when the recursion unwinds, the partial sequences are also printed. To avoid that, add the following condition :

```
    if (n==0||k==0||k>n) {
        if (k==0) // this condition will make sure that only complete
                  // sequences of k elements will be printed
            System.out.println(sequence);
    } else {
        showTeam(sequence+start,(char)(start+1),n-1,k-1);
        showTeam(sequence,(char)(start+1),n-1,k);
    }
```

Output :

```
ABC
ABD
ABE
ACD
ACE
ADE
BCD
BCE
BDE
CDE
```

Comment: This seemed to almost fix the problem. But it still prints out sequences whose length is less than the teamSize(k). How should I go about it?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
start++
```

use

```
start + 1
```

If you use **`start++`**, the `start` **variable will be increased only after the recursion** and not before calling the recursion.

Using `start + 1` you pass the new value as parameter.

---

In java there are 3 different operators that can be used to increment by one a variable:

- start + 1
- start++
- ++start

start + 1 is an expression which value is start + 1, and it doesn't increment start.

start++ is an expression which value is start (not start + 1), and it increments start by 1

++start is an expression which value is start + 1 and it increments start by 1.

Here an example with an initial value of 5.

```
                      start + 1         start++           ++start
                      ---------         -------          --------
 initial start value      5                 5                5
 end start value          5                 6                6
 expression value         6                 5                6
```

Note that `start + 1` doesn't really change `start`. You need a code like `start = start + 1` to change it.

In your code, you are not interested on changing the value of start inside the current method. You need only to pass start + 1 to the recursion.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I feel somewhat unclear of the difference between start++ and start+1. Aren't they both just incermenting the character to next character in my case A to B to C to D to E.

Comment: While this answer explains nicely the difference between `start+1`, `start++` and `++start`, it only addresses one of the problems in the OP's code. Simply changing `start++` to `start+1` not only won't give the correct output, it won't even pass compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the same program from my collection...

```
public class TeamSelector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sequence = "";
        int groupSize = 5;
        int teamSize = 3;
        showTeams(groupSize, teamSize, sequence, 'A', teamSize - 1);
    }

    public static void showTeams(int groupSize, int teamSize, String sequence, 
                                                char groupMember, int validNode) {
        if (teamSize > groupSize || groupSize < 0 || teamSize < 0) return;

        sequence += Character.toString(groupMember);
        groupMember++;
        // Left call
        showTeams(groupSize - 1, teamSize - 1, sequence, groupMember, validNode);
        sequence = sequence.substring(0, sequence.length() - 1);

        if (sequence.length() == validNode) {
            System.out.println(sequence + (char) (groupMember - 1));
        }
        // Right call
        showTeams(groupSize - 1, teamSize, sequence, groupMember, validNode);
        groupMember--;
    }
}
```